# MySQL while loop won't stop

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I've recently created a PHP/MySQL while loop which fetches an array based on my parameters. From what I know about doing this, it should end when there are no more rows to grab. Mine just keeps going until I stop the page loading.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT username,password,title,message FROM notifications WHERE dateset = '$date'"))){
    $test = new Boxcar($row['username'],$row['password']); 
    $test->send($row['title'],$row['message']);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try like this
most likely the inline query is being rerun everytime you step through the while loop

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT username,password,title,message FROM notifications WHERE dateset = '$date'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $test = new Boxcar($row['username'],$row['password']); 
    $test->send($row['title'],$row['message']);
}
```

Comment: Yeah that worked, but why does it matter if the query is in a variable. Isn't while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) just  

Hi all, I've recently created a PHP/MySQL while loop which fetches an array based on my parameters. From what I know about doing this, it should end when there are no more rows to grab. Mine just keeps going until I stop the page loading.

while($row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT username,password,title,message FROM notifications WHERE dateset = '$date'"))) anyway?

Comment: @Sam: the reason the original failed was because every time the loop goes back to the start, it calls that query again (as part of the comparison) and so every time, you get a new result set and start back at the start...